# Integrating Aurelia in existing MVC Application

Tags: node.js, asp.net-mvc, typescript, github, aurelia

I have an application in MVC 4.5 using VS 2015.

To this existing application, a new module has to be developed and what I'm trying is to develop this using **Aurelia** framework.I had fair bit of experience in aurelia framework.Hence I want to integrate our existing MVC application with Aurelia but unable to achieve this while routing.Hence posting this here in this platform.

These are the links that I went through for this purpose :
 - [Link1](http://ruimourato.com/2016/01/26/running-aurelia-on-mvc5.html)
 - [Link2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3glCUG8X_Fc)
 - [Link3](http://blog.nojaf.com/2015/05/06/using-razor-partials-cshtml-with-aurelia-components/)
 - [Link4](https://github.com/AllenHunn/aurelia-mvc)
 - [Link5](https://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/getting-started-with-aurelia-in-aspnet-mvc-EH)

To some extent I'm able to achieve this.From my partial view when the request is sent to **main.js** setRoot to app.html, this routes to app.js, but any kind of code written there results in Invalid Token Syntax error even if I write just one line of code in app.js.
[image]

Also, trying to set route in app.js results in route not found error :[image]
This is what I tried:

- Created an standalone aurelia app, wrote code in app.ts and was able
  to render grid chart in corresponding html(app.html).
- Created an MVC application(followed one of the above link) by adding one view , then routing to app.js through main and was able to render the page.
- Also, I tried with normal routing like [this](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/master/skeleton-esnext/src/app.js) in app.js.It resulted in error as cant find route.

What I'm ultimately trying to achieve is , when I click on any sub-tab(as I've Tab/Sub-tab views) and my partial view(cshtml) gets rendered, it should route to the aurelia app and render the content in that particular section with result.

Is this feasible or am I missing something here?? Any help would be highly appreciated..